# how to call id parameter store in arraylist using json android

Tags: android

In this method work properly but not working id parameter, please help me.

How to get id and how to store id.

```
public void getAccountDetail_httpCall( ) {
try {
    int TIMEOUT_MILLISEC = 10000; // = 10 seconds

    String param1="25";

    HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams,TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, TIMEOUT_MILLISEC);

    HttpParams p = new BasicHttpParams();       

    p.setParameter("id",  param1);//param1      
        // Instantiate an HttpClient
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(p);
    String   url="http://www.tranzlogix.comtranzlogix_webserviceonesms.php?smsid="+param1+"&format=json";//param1
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
    // Instantiate a GET HTTP method
    try {
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "web service called-----");
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(),"URL---"+url);

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id", param1));//param1
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String responseBody = httpclient.execute(httppost,
                responseHandler);
        Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "responseBody----"+responseBody);

        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        JSONArray jArray = json.getJSONArray("posts");

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            JSONObject e = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            String s = e.getString("post");
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(s);


            map.put("message", jObject.getString("message"));
            map.put("mobile", jObject.getString("mobile"));
            map.put("id", jObject.getString("id"));

            Util.mylist.add(map);
        }

        for(int i=0;i<=Util.mylist.size();i++){
            Util.mobile.add(Util.mylist.get(i).get("mobile"));

            Util.id.add(Util.mylist.get(i).get("id"));
            Util.message.add(Util.mylist.get(i).get("message"));

            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "mobile             no's----"+Util.mylist.get(i).get("mobile"));
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "id no's----"+Util.mylist.get(i).get("id"));
            Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "message's----"+Util.mylist.get(i).get("message"));

        String phoneNo = Util.mylist.get(i).get("mobile");
        //String phoneNo = Util.mylist.get(i).get("id");
            String message =Util. mylist.get(i).get("message");             
            if (phoneNo.length()>0 && message.length()>0)               
                sendSMS(phoneNo, message);              
            else
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), 
                    "Please enter both phone number and message.", 
                  Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        }

        // new PaymentSubmit().execute();
    //  Util.id=mylist.get(0).get("id");

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        } catch (Throwable t) {
        }
```

how can i set multiple parameter...

Comment: can you specify about the issue with ID? and What multiple parameter you are referring to?

Comment: iam getting an id with many datas and storing it inside an arraylist,i have to call that id inside an URL with an parameter so that all the datas inside the arraylist have to be called automatically.currently iam setting the positions of the array list manually how to set the arraylist's entire data..